# How to resign or crack an Android app which is protected against resigning

Tags: android, apk, android-espresso, jar-signing

I'm doing a black-box Espresso UI testing on an app which I only have the apk file. To run the Espresso test, the app to be tested and the test have to be signed with the same signature, so I have to resign the app apk.
I have tried to resign the app with these commands:

```
zip -d $APK META-INF/\*
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore $KEYSTORE -storepass $STOREPASS $APK $ALIAS
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs $APK
zipalign -v 4 $APK $ALIGNED_APK
```

The resigned app was installed successfully. But, it couldn't be launched. Here is the log from logcat:

```
11-03 11:12:08.546: I/ActivityManager(1020): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.zg.zl/.ui.SplashActivity u=0} from pid 1128
11-03 11:12:08.546: W/WindowManager(1020): Failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21005
11-03 11:12:08.556: D/dalvikvm(795): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
11-03 11:12:08.586: D/dalvikvm(795): GC_EXPLICIT freed 37K, 4% free 7917K/8195K, paused 0ms+1ms, total 27ms
11-03 11:12:08.586: D/dalvikvm(795): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
11-03 11:12:08.596: D/dalvikvm(795): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 4% free 7917K/8195K, paused 0ms+1ms, total 5ms
11-03 11:12:08.596: I/ActivityManager(1020): Start proc com.zg.zl for activity com.zg.zl/.ui.SplashActivity: pid=1587 uid=10044 gids={3003, 1015, 1006, 3002, 1028}
11-03 11:12:08.606: D/dalvikvm(795): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
11-03 11:12:08.606: D/dalvikvm(795): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 4% free 7917K/8195K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 6ms
11-03 11:12:08.617: E/Trace(1587): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-03 11:12:08.646: D/dalvikvm(1587): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
11-03 11:12:08.716: D/dalvikvm(1587): GC_CONCURRENT freed 155K, 3% free 8200K/8391K, paused 21ms+1ms, total 40ms
11-03 11:12:08.756: D/dalvikvm(1587): GC_CONCURRENT freed 118K, 3% free 8497K/8711K, paused 15ms+0ms, total 21ms
11-03 11:12:08.806: D/dalvikvm(1587): GC_CONCURRENT freed 127K, 3% free 8808K/9031K, paused 12ms+0ms, total 17ms
11-03 11:12:08.816: I/ActivityThread(1587): Pub com.zg.zl.db.preferencesprovider: com.zg.zl.db.PreferencesProvider
11-03 11:12:08.826: D/dalvikvm(1587): Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.zg.zl-1/lib/libzl_native_lib.so 0xb55cfc48
11-03 11:12:08.826: D/dalvikvm(1587): Added shared lib /mnt/asec/com.zg.zl-1/lib/libzl_native_lib.so 0xb55cfc48
11-03 11:12:08.826: D/dalvikvm(1587): Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.zg.zl-1/lib/libzl_native_lib.so 0xb55cfc48
11-03 11:12:08.826: D/dalvikvm(1587): Shared lib '/mnt/asec/com.zg.zl-1/lib/libzl_native_lib.so' already loaded in same CL 0xb55cfc48
11-03 11:12:08.826: I/AndroidRuntime(1587): VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.
11-03 11:12:08.846: I/ActivityManager(1020): Process com.zg.zl (pid 1587) has died.
11-03 11:12:08.846: W/ActivityManager(1020): Force removing ActivityRecord{b59377c8 com.zg.zl/.ui.SplashActivity}: app died, no saved state
11-03 11:12:08.886: W/InputMethodManagerService(1020): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@b59228a0 attribute=null
11-03 11:13:16.597: D/dalvikvm(1116): GC_CONCURRENT freed 384K, 7% free 8482K/9031K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 7ms
```

(If I remove the `META-INF` folder from the resigned apk, and add the `META-INF` folder which is from the original APK. The app can be installed and run normally.)

I think the app is protected against being resigned with a different certificate. How can I work around this problem?

Comment: Get a new, properly signed version from devs. Otherwise it's hard to convince anyone that you only do "Black box testing"

Comment: Espresso was not built with "black box" testing in mind, so the signing will not be your only issue. Take a look at UiAutomator ( http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html )

Comment: @yogurtearl I was aware of UiAutomator, but it's only available from API 16 (Android 4.1) onward. Besides, UiAutomator is slow and flaky when compared to Expresso. You are right that signing isn't the only issue. But I did experiment with the testapp and testapp_test in the Espresso repo (https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/source/browse/). Assuming in practice I don't have the source code of the testapp, I was able to convert the classes.dex (of the compiled testapp) to jar and import it to the testing project (testapp_test). Finally, I resigned the testapp and the test ran just fine.

Answer (score 1):

As I read somewhere, knowing how to pick a lock doesn't make you a robber.
Since this question haven't received any answers. I would like to point someone
at the right direction if they are interested.

First, you need to decomile/desassemble the app to smali code. A wellknown tool
for this is `apktool`/`baksmali`. `dex2jar` and `jd-gui` can be used to reverse
the app to java code which is useful to understand the smali code.

Second, If an app have some types of protection, it must make certain API calls. By
searching for the API call, you can identify what code you need to modify. In
this case, the java code could be like this:

```
Context mContext = MainApplication.getApplicationContext();
byte[] signatureByteArray = mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(mContext.getPackageName(), 64).signatures[0].toByteArray();
```

The equivalent smali code would be:

```
:try_start_0
invoke-static {}, Lcom/zing/zalo/app/MainApplication;->it()Landroid/content/Context;
move-result-object v1
invoke-virtual {v1}, Landroid/content/Context;->getPackageManager()Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;
move-result-object v2
invoke-virtual {v1}, Landroid/content/Context;->getPackageName()Ljava/lang/String;
move-result-object v1
const/16 v3, 0x40
invoke-virtual {v2, v1, v3}, Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;->getPackageInfo(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/content/pm/PackageInfo;
move-result-object v1
iget-object v1, v1, Landroid/content/pm/PackageInfo;->signatures:[Landroid/content/pm/Signature;
const/4 v2, 0x0
aget-object v1, v1, v2
invoke-virtual {v1}, Landroid/content/pm/Signature;->toByteArray()[B
move-result-object v1
```

In practice, apps are usually obfuscated and the app can be protected against
modification by other means such as checking the file size. Here is just a
general idea.